# RTMP port 80 is being blocked for some users, what can I do

Tags: streaming, audio-streaming, flash-media-server, fms3

I'm using Flash Media Server to stream audio. I used to use it on port 1935 (the default port) but a lot of users were complaining they couldn't hear the stream, I figured it may be a firewall issue and their firewall was blocking that port. So I changed it to port 80 and most of the users who couldn't stream properly, were now able to.

Ever since then, i've still encountered a few users who complain about not hearing the stream. I'm not really sure where to go from here, I would have thought port 80 is open for everyone seeing as HTTP goes through port 80 and if you can browse the web then you should be able to stream right? Clearly not... Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can do my end to enable streaming for these users who can't hear anything port 80?

Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In some organizations, there is an intelligent firewall or some device that does deep packet inspection.  These devices can be configured to analyze the data running over a port, and flag it accordingly.

So, you sent RTMP over port 80, the device recognizes it and will usually do one of two things:

- "Hey, that's RTMP being sent over the wrong port!  Not on my watch!! [BLAM, packet killed]"
- "Hey, that's RTMP being sent over the HTTP port!  Let's not apply rules for HTTP and apply the packet shaping rule for RTMP, which says it should be blocked (or throttled down to 0.03kbps)"

Unfortunately, there's not much you can do about this.  It is very common for this kind of thing to get blocked or throttled near the client's end.

If you can find someone this happens for, you can analyze the packets with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html), or some other packet sniffing software.  Then you can see for sure what is reaching the client, and what isn't.